# Export version 3 public key to PGP server

Tags: pgp

I've a public key which is V3 that I need to export to export to a PGP server, any suggestion? Have tried to export [here](https://keyserver.pgp.com/vkd/GetWelcomeScreen.event) but it says:

```
No V3 Keys Allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 3 OpenPGP keys are deprecated and shouldn't be used any more. Consider generating a new key instead. There is no way to migrate a v3 key to the new v4 format.

Then, you speak about "export[ing] to a PGP server". There is no such thing as *a* PGP server: there are lots of them. You reference a specific one hosted by Symantec, the current owner of the proprietary PGP implementation, but there is also a variety of other OpenPGP keyservers. Most of them are organized in the [SKS kekyservers pool](http://sks-keyservers.net/) and can be [queried through pool.sks-keyservers.net](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net). These keyservers allow deprecated v3 keys.